# Populating the ionic historic framework

Tags: android, mobile, ionic-framework

I need to know how to populate the history of ionic framework. of the own window i know it well:

```
 window.history.pushState({upage:sel}, sel, document.location.origin + document.location.pathname +sel);
```

My problem is that I need to record the be worthily celebrated "name" of the pages in that i spent for the click the Back button again he should native previous vision, this way using the method to return the window returns only a vision.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to manipulate the history, you can pass some options to each controller in order to change the behavior when it's only a stacking/manipulation purpose.

Hope this snippets helps !

```js
// Jump to state "first-state"
$state.go('first-state', {options: values, title: "Custom title"}).then(function() {
    // Make this state the Root (or not, or at another step)
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();

    // Jump to "another-state"
    $state.go('another-state', {options: values}).then(function() {
        // [...]
        $state.go('another-jump', {options: values});
    });
});
```